# How to implement search in listbox wp7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

How to implement search in listbox(ObservableCollection)? Is the wp7 has something default for this?

[image]

Comment: ANSWER: onlines_filter.TextChanged += (a, v) => { ((App)App.Current).FriendsOnlines.View.Refresh(); };

Comment: why don't you reset the Filter instead of Refresh the view ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the Autocomplete textbox which is part of the [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

i think the control of Autocomplete can help you.